# arcpy.GetCount_managment not returning result in dialog window

Tags: arcpy

I am having trouble with GetCount to work in my script. It is not printing the GetCount arcpy.AddMessage in the geoprocessing window dialog;

```
# Get the spatial reference
 spatialRef = arcpy.Describe(template).spatialReference.name

#Loop through shapfiles in folder and reproject
 for fc in fcList:
     fcspatialRef = arcpy.Describe(fc).spatialReference.name
     if fcspatialRef != spatialRef:
         arcpy.AddMessage(fc)
         arcpy.Project_management(fc, outFolder + "\\" + fc, template)
         projCount = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(fc).getOutput(0)) 
     else:
         arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fc, outFolder + "\\" + fc)

# Get the count from GetCount's Result object
     arcpy.AddMessage("{0} datasets have been reprojected to: {1} and saved in {2}".format(projCount, spatialRef, OutFolder))
```

Comment: GetCount counts the number of features in one feature class, not the number of datasets in a workspace. Are you trying to print the latter?

Comment: In addition, projCount will not be printed if the 'else' condition is met.

Comment: Yes GISGe, I am trying to do the latter. Oh, I've seen that result, lol and couldn't work out why that number was appearing.. I want to know many datasets (ie4) have been reprojected. Do you have a suggestion on what  I should be using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to print the number of datasets that have been projected (not those that have just been copied), you should then create a 'count' variable and increment it each time you project a dataset. Be careful with the indentation of your code, the message must be added outside the loop (once, after all datasets have been reviewed).

```
count = 0
#Loop through shapfiles in folder and reproject
for fc in fcList:
  fcspatialRef = arcpy.Describe(fc).spatialReference.name
    if fcspatialRef != spatialRef:
      arcpy.AddMessage(fc)
      arcpy.Project_management(fc, outFolder + "\\" + fc, template)
      count += 1
    else:
      arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fc, outFolder + "\\" + fc)

# print the count variable
arcpy.AddMessage("{0} datasets have been reprojected to: {1} and saved in {2}".format(count, spatialRef, OutFolder))
```

Comment: You can create a separate count variable (e.g. count2) before the loop, and increment it the same way but under the else block.